# Micro Focus ALM Synchronizer: Fetching endpoint schema error

Tags: tfs, synchronization, tfs-2015, alm, microfocus

I am trying to set up a Synchronizer link between ALM and TFS2015.

The integrity check indicates that on the TFS side it fails in a "Fetching endpoint schema" step with the error : Micro Focus ALM Synchronizer - Report

buildEntitySchema: disconnected Error converting value "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;---some-long-sid-----" to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityDescriptor'. Path 'authenticatedUser.descriptor', line 1, position 167.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a know issue with HPE. KM02568091 references this issue

https://eyeontesting.com/questions/13275/hp-alm-synchronizer-version-1250-error-for-link-cr.html?sort=oldest